# Firebase RealTime Database: When I remove a value from a database, why it creates a download steam from the Realtime Database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, download, upload

I am trying to remove a value in the RTDB as below:

```
FirebaseDatabase
            .getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child(userId)
            .child(key)
            .child("2")
            .setValue(null);
```

**I understand the upload is 0B as I am setting a "null" value. But why there is a 47B download Bytes which is referring to the length of my path?**

Since download bandwidth will be charged by Firebase, I would like to understand more.

[image]